# Module not found: Turborepo wildcard imports

Tags: turborepo

When using Turborepo's wildcard imports (snippet from package.json)

```js
dependencies: {
  "branding": "*"
}
```

inside of a React app created with create-react-app, I get the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 5:0-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'branding' in 'C:\Users\****\Projects\Development\monorepo\apps\share\src'
```

I think I'm doing something very wrong, but I can't work it out through Turborepo's documentation.